# The method onActivityCreated(bundle) is undefined for the type SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, bundle, undefined

I'm trying to work on a project that implements actionBarSherlock, I've added the library to the project properly and I get this error:

```
The method onActivityCreated(bundle) is undefined for the type SherlockFragment
```

This is the code from the project:

```
public class A_class extends SherlockFragment implements
    OnClickListener { ... }
```

I think the answer is quite simple but I can't work it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

If you want to use a fragment with sherlock features use `SherlockFragment`. In this case you cannot have activity related method since its a "Fragment"

Otherwise you are looking for `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Comment: Yeah that's ok...but you can accept the answer by clicking a right mark that you can see on left side of my answer. Glad I could help